# Turning OFF mock location

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have an app that will not open on my new Samsung Galaxy S6. It says the mock location setting must be turned off. I went to developer settings, but there is no check box next to mock locations to check or uncheck. It states "none" beside it. How do I turn it off? The app techs were not able to help.

Answer (score 0):

After you selected as a developer in settings, in the Debugging session, you're going to select a "box" -> "Allow mock location". I suggest to restart your phone and try to use your "app" again.

Comment: For further info, please access this video that I found on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUw2Z55iKsk